# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to check on this class if it is exist in my DOM or not so i can then add some actions depending on it. but it keep giving me this error.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {


            function hasClass(ele, cls) {
              return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
            }

            if (hasClass(document.querySelector('.mobile-wrapper'), 'mobile-wrapper')) {
              console.log('yes');
            } else {
              console.log('no');
            }
          });
```

the class is not available now in my DOM

Comment: Well, if `querySelector` doesn't return anything, then `ele` is `null`, hence the error. More importantly though… you're selecting an element by class name, and then test whether it has that class name…?! Makes no sense.

Comment: you are actually right but i have tried many things and nothing worked

Comment: could you not just check like this 
   if(document.querySelector('.mobile-wrapper')!==null)

Comment: `if (document.querySelector('.mobile-wrapper')) console.log('yes')` - that's all you need. Having said that, it looks like you're trying to use Angular like jQuery; there are probably much better solutions to whatever you're trying to do in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check class in pure JS you need to write this `element.classList.contains('some-class')`

Comment: I have done this before but i still get the same error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined
 if (angular.element(document).classList.contains('uber-mobile-wrapper'))